# Selecting a custom color in an applet

Tags: java, swing, colors, applet, slider

I am creating a paint program in java for class. The user needs to be able to define custom colors to paint with. I figure the best way to go about this would be to have an icon the user clicks on, resulting in a pop-up selection window with sliders to define the three RGB values of a color. What would be the best way to go about this? I've found `JSlider` but can't figure out how to implement it as a pop-up window as a result of an icon being clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `JColorChooser`.  See [How to Use Color Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html) for details.

[image: Color Chooser]

Comment: Now how would I go about implementing this as a popup window in an applet? Can it even be or do I need an application for this to work?

Comment: Do the tutorial, most of your questions will be answered.  Specifically, the chooser can be embedded in, or popped from, a frame, an applet, a window, a dialog..